# How to disable dates for older posts in Blogger

Tags: blogger

I want to disable showing dates for some of my old posts which are timeless. I have a blogger blog, and I am not very sure how to do that by modifying blogger template. I know that blogger template support conditions. Is there are way to enable/disable date for a particular blog post or a subset of blog post?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove those dates from all posts.

> Go to template first
>   Then click on edit as below.

[image]

> Then hide or enable below options as you like

[image]